# Injection / Surjection

Tags: functions

Here's the question

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/e551c8cf063efcacee23cf0c49199b42.png?1366636924))</sub>

I got that it is injective. By saying:

$f(y) = 3 - y^2$

Suppose;

$f(x) = f(y)$

$3 - x^2 = 3 - y^2$

$x^2 = y^2$

$sqrt(x) = sqrt(y)$

$±x = ±y $

I conclude the it's not injective because $ -x =!$ $y$ Is this the right way to come to this conclusion?

I'm not sure how to find out if it's surjective or not.

Comment: That's not quite right since you've simply shown that that line of reasoning doesn't show $x=y$. It would be better to find two particular real numbers that get sent to the same number. Your calculation suggests taking say $1$ and $-1$. To show a failure of surjectivity, you also only need to find a single number not in the range.

Answer (score 4):

That is the right way of testing whether or not it is injective, although personally I would prefer to use $a$ and $b$ instead of $x$ and $y$. As for surjectivity, try to solve $f(x) = 4$.

Comment: To me, it looks like the OP's reasoning is $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=\pm y$, which is not sufficient to show it's not injective. If you take the reasoning to be an if and only if, that's different.

Comment: Is $4$ just a random number? Why 4?

Comment: @AdegokeA $4$ is a "slightly" random number. The important thing is that it is larger than $3$. As the constant term is $3$, and the $-x^2$ term cannot be positive, the calue of the function is never larger than $3$, so trying to solve for any such value would yield a negative result. Other examples include $\pi$, $\sqrt{10}$ and a million.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip When I determine injectivity, that is the way I usually go. If you can show that $f(x) = f(y)\Rightarrow x=y$ then the function is injective, and if you get anything else, it's more often than not a large hint in the hunt for a pair of different inputs yielding the same outputs, in this case $x=-y$.

Comment: @Arthur: I agree that it is a large hint, just not the complete proof.

Answer (score 4):

First, drawing a picture for something like this in invaluable:

[image]

Injective means that if $f(x)=f(x')$ then you must have $x=x'$. You can see that $f(1)=f(-1)$ for example, so it cannot be injective.

Surjective means that for any $y$ in the range, there is some $x$ in the domain such that $f(x) = y$. Since $x^2 \ge 0$ for any $x$, you can see that $f(x) \le 3$ for all $x$. Hence any point $y>3$ cannot be in the range and so it is not surjective.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just trying to get my head around this. So if $x = 1$, it's compliment is $-1$, right? But for injection, $x$ must equal $x'$. Can you give me an example where $x$ actually equals to $x'$. I can't think of any.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding "$x$ actually equals $x'$". It means that there aren't two distinct $x$ values; they are the same.

Comment: @AdegokeA: The function is injective iff whenever $f(x)=f(x')$ then you must have $x=x'$. In the above picture, you can draw a horizontal line through the graph. If the line is $y=2$ for example, it intersects the graph twice which means there are two $x$ values that product the same $y$ value. Hence is cannot be injective.

Comment: I totally get that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a good calculation, that will help you find an answer.  To prove a function is NOT injective you need a single counterexample.  Using your calculation, let's pick some $x,y$ that we expect will map to the same place.  For example, $x=4, y=-4$.  Then $f(4)=3-4^2=-13$ and $f(y)=3-(-4)^2=3-16=-13$.

To determine if it's surjective, let $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and try to find some $x$ such that $f(x)=a$. (i.e. solve for $x$).  If you succeed regardless of $a$, you've proved it's surjective.  If you fail for some $a$, you will have a roadmap to find a counterexample.

Comment: I only understand how this works when I imagine two sets, A & B. So 4 is A and -4 is B. Injection means that for every element in A, there's a uniqe one in B, right? But because there's limit, which in 3, right? -13 is then invalid. Is any of what I said right?

Comment: $4,-4$ are both in $A$.  $f:A\rightarrow B$.

Comment: ^no. A function is a rule that assigns elements in A to elements in B. "For every element in A, there is a unique element in B" is part of the function being defined on the domain A. "For every b in B, there is a unique a in A such that f(a) = b" is injective

Comment: @Chaz: The goal is to prove that $f$ is *not* injective.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 This is how I like to define it. Injective means that every member of "A" has its own unique matching member in "B".[link](http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/injective-surjective-bijective.html)

Comment: @vadim123 Well yes, but I don't know if it's injective or not at the start. The goal is to find out. So 4 & -4 are both elements of A, right? And they can't both be mapped to the same element in B, making the function NOT injective, right?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method

1.Draw Graph 
 2.Draw Horizontal lines. If any horizontal line intersects the graph more than once,then the graph is not injective. 

 I hope I have illustrated that and surjectivity in the image :)

:[image]

Answer (score 0):

A function is **injective** if each element in the codomain is mapped to by *at most* one element in the domain.$$\forall x_1\in \Bbb R~~\forall x_2\in\Bbb R:(f(x_1){=}f(x_2)\to x_1{=}x_2)$$

As you have shown, there exists some elements in the codomain which are mapped to by *more than* one element in the domain.  That does indeed allow you to declare that the function is *not* injective.    Well done.

---

A function is **surjective** if every element in the codomain is mapped to by *at least* one element in the domain.  Ie: The entire codomain is the image of the domain.

$$\forall y\in\Bbb R~~\exists x\in\Bbb R:y=f(x)\\[2ex]\Bbb R=f(\Bbb R)$$

So are there any elements in the codomain ($\Bbb R$) which are not in the image of the domain?